# Make react-native in IOS working in android

Tags: react-native

I am very new in react-native and try to find a start-up project in github to learn and finally I found one app in github that I think is very cool to learn. The problem this app is targeted for IOS not for android. Is it possible to make this working in android as well without a lot of effort?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup but it will depend on components that were used in the app , if it was targeting only IOS you have to replace it with components that works on both iOS and android

For example TabBarIOS is a react native component that works only on IOS , but there's many tab bar implementations that works on both iOS and android.